# Unit testing ASP.NET MVC redirection

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

How do I Unit Test a MVC redirection?

```
public ActionResult Create(Product product)
{
    _productTask.Save(product);
    return RedirectToAction("Success");   
}

public ActionResult Success()
{ 
     return View();
}
```

Is [Ayende's](http://www.ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/12/13/Dont-like-visibility-levels-change-that.aspx) approach still the best way to go, with preview 5:

```
 public static void RenderView(this Controller self, string action) 
 {
    typeof(Controller).GetMethod("RenderView").Invoke(self,new object[] { action} ); 
 }
```

Seems odd to have to do this, especially as the MVC team have said they are writing the framework to be testable.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
[TestFixture]
public class RedirectTester
{
    [Test]
    public void Should_redirect_to_success_action()
    {
        var controller = new RedirectController();
        var result = controller.Index() as RedirectToRouteResult;
        Assert.That(result, Is.Not.Null);
        Assert.That(result.Values["action"], Is.EqualTo("success"));
    }
}

public class RedirectController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("success");
    }
}
```

Comment: RedirectToRouteResult.Values[] is now RedirectToRouteResult.RouteValues[...]

Comment: does anyone know how you can actually have the action invoked when redirected during testing ?

Comment: @f0ster Why would you want that? Either way, `controller.Success()` in the above example would accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

This works for ASP.NET MVC 5 using NUnit:

```
    [Test]
    public void ShouldRedirectToSuccessAction()
    {
        var controller = new RedirectController();
        var result = controller.Index() as RedirectToRouteResult;

        Assert.That(result.RouteValues["action"], Is.EqualTo("success"));
    }
```

If you want to test that you are redirecting to a different controller (say NewController), the assertion would be:

```
Assert.That(result.RouteValues["controller"], Is.EqualTo("New"));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can assert on the ActionResult that is returned, you'll need to cast it to the appropriate type but it does allow you to use state-based testing. A search on the Web should find some useful links, here's [just one](http://sebastienlachance.com/2008/05/06/testing-controllers-in-aspnet-mvc-aka-actionresult/) though.

Answer (score -1):

you can use Mvc.Contrib.TestHelper which provides assertions for testing redirections. Take a look at http://kbochevski.blogspot.com/2010/06/unit-testing-mvcnet.html and the code sample. It might be helpful.

Comment: Per the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion)  `"Be careful, because the community frowns on overt self-promotion and tends to vote it down and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if they happen to be about your product or website, so be it. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers. Also, if a huge percentage of your posts include a mention of your product or website, you're probably here for the wrong reasons."`