# Redirection in unittest

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, nunit

How do I Unit Test a MVC redirection?

```
public ActionResult Create(Product product)
{

    _productTask.Save(product);

    return RedirectToAction("Index",new {id = product.Id});

}

public ActionResult Index(int id)
{

    return View();
}
```

Here i used the unit testing statements as

```
 var result = controller.CreateGroup(group) as RedirectToRouteResult;
    //// Assert 
    Assert.That(result, Is.Not.Null);
```

but it fails result returns null value
can anyone please help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unit testing MVC.net Redirection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58513/unit-testing-mvc-net-redirection)

Comment: is there any change from the Unit testing MVC.net Redirection when we redirect to an action with parameter

Answer (score 0):

```
// Arrange
var product = new Product(){Id=1};

// Act
var result = controller.Create(product);

// Assert
result.AssertActionRedirect()
                .ToController("thisControllerName")
                .ToAction("Index");
```

Comment: I used this one but still it is not returning the value the result value is null